# clang: error: linker command

Tags: ios, xcode, linker

I am trying not to bother anybody here after getting spanked by the community for my last question. Sorry but I have been trying to find the answer for a week. I know that people here dont like to help others learn coding but I need to solve this and if I get yelled at I get yelled at so here goes;

I am getting the following error;

ld: framework not found ParseUI for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have been doing things in terminal like many people have been telling others but I cant fix this. I really dont know if it is my code or my brand new MacBook pro running Sierra. I am running xcode 9.1.

I am sorry to bother people here but I am seriously stuck.

cd /Users/rogerschroeder/Desktop/DogTrainingApp
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator11.1.sdk -L/Users/rogerschroeder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DogTrainingApp-atwbaysopzwnnjgrzzbrvzspbibm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/rogerschroeder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DogTrainingApp-atwbaysopzwnnjgrzzbrvzspbibm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/rogerschroeder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DogTrainingApp-atwbaysopzwnnjgrzzbrvzspbibm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DogTrainingApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DogTrainingAppTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DogTrainingAppTests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -bundle_loader /Users/rogerschroeder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DogTrainingApp-atwbaysopzwnnjgrzzbrvzspbibm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DogTrainingApp.app/DogTrainingApp -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/rogerschroeder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DogTrainingApp-atwbaysopzwnnjgrzzbrvzspbibm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DogTrainingApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DogTrainingAppTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DogTrainingAppTests_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/rogerschroeder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DogTrainingApp-atwbaysopzwnnjgrzzbrvzspbibm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DogTrainingApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DogTrainingAppTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DogTrainingAppTests.swiftmodule -framework XCTest -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/rogerschroeder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DogTrainingApp-atwbaysopzwnnjgrzzbrvzspbibm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DogTrainingApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DogTrainingAppTests.build/DogTrainingAppTests.xctest.xcent -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/rogerschroeder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DogTrainingApp-atwbaysopzwnnjgrzzbrvzspbibm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DogTrainingApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/DogTrainingAppTests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DogTrainingAppTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/rogerschroeder/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DogTrainingApp-atwbaysopzwnnjgrzzbrvzspbibm/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DogTrainingApp.app/PlugIns/DogTrainingAppTests.xctest/DogTrainingAppTests

ld: framework not found ParseUI for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: ParseUI framework is obviously missing or not linked to the target you are trying to build.

Comment: Or, to put it another way, where is the ParseUI framework located and how do you reference it in your app project?

Comment: The ParseUI framework is in the frameworks folder and there is no question mark behind it. Could it be that it is not hooked up to the parse server?

Comment: Thank you for replying I feel embarrassed for asking stupid questions but after working on this for a week...

Comment: The code was originally written in 7 and I am trying to open it up in 9 if this provides any clues. One of my view controllers has a big "M" after it.

Comment: Well i guess u copied that project to another machine and now u r getting such error! Am i right ? If it is true, then u hv to install that framework once again for your new system.. it seems like that framework got miss in your new mac.

Comment: The error is obvious -- the linker can't find the framework, but the cause may not be.  :)  Are you using cocoa pods to manage the framework?  If not, do you have its location **on disk** included in the framework path of your target's build options? (Your "M" probably means you have source control turned on and the file has been modified.)

Comment: You are right that I copied the project to a new mac so yes you are right. I have been looking around to see how to install a new framework into my system but I am spinning my wheels.

Comment: I dont think I am using cocoa pods. I am also researching how to find that out. Im sorry for not knowing.